Why does Python remove wrong element from the list?
I am trying to make an algorithm that would parse a pyramid of numbers such as:
75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23
Algorithm would then start from the top and compare the sum of far left column and far right column and remove the one with lower sum.
My code looks like this:
`your text`input1="""75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23"""


input2=input1.split("\n")
input3=[]
for i in input2:
    a=i.split()
    input3.append(a)


def _rightislarger(list1):
    sum1=0
    sum2=0

    
    for i in list1:
        print("-right path-")
        print(i[0])
        sum1+=int(i[0])
        print("---")
    for i in list1:
        print("-left path-")
        print(i[-1])
        sum2+=int(i[-1])
        print("---")
    print(f"comparing {sum1} with {sum2}")
    if sum1>sum2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

working_list=input3

path1=[]


while len(working_list) > 0:
    print(working_list)
    path1.append(working_list[0][0])
    working_list.remove(working_list[0])
    if _rightislarger(working_list):
        for i in working_list:
            print(f"removing {i[-1]}")
            i.remove(i[-1])
    
    else:
        for i in working_list:
            i.remove(i[0])




path1=list(map(int, path1))

    
print(path1, sum(path1))


After first itteration of the while loop, the list goes from this:
[['**75**'],
['95', **'64'**], 
['17', '47', **'82'**], 
['18', '35', '87', **'10'**], 
['20', '04', '82', '47', **'65'**], 
['19', '01', '23', '75', '03', **'34'**], 
['88', '02', '77', '73', '07', '63', **'67'**], 
['99', '65', '04', '28', '06', '16', '70', **'92'**], 
['41', '41', '26', '56', '83', '40', '80', '70', **'33'**], 
['41', '48', '72', '33', '47', '32', '37', '16', '94', **'29'**], 
['53', '71', '44', '65', '25', '43', '91', '52', '97', '51', **'14'**], 
['70', '11', '33', '28', '77', '73', '17', '78', '39', '68', '17', **'57'**], 
['91', '71', '52', '38', '17', '14', '91', '43', '58', '50', '27', '29', **'48'**], 
['63', '66', '04', '68', '89', '53', '67', '30', '73', '16', '69', '87', '40', **'31'**], 
['04', '62', '98', '27', *'23'*, '09', '70', '98', '73', '93', '38', '53', '60', '04', **'23'**]]

to this:
[['95'], 
['17', '47'], 
['18', '35', '87'], 
['20', '04', '82', '47'], 
['19', '01', '23', '75', '03'], 
['88', '02', '77', '73', '07', '63'], 
['99', '65', '04', '28', '06', '16', '70'], 
['41', '41', '26', '56', '83', '40', '80', '70'], 
['41', '48', '72', '33', '47', '32', '37', '16', '94'], 
['53', '71', '44', '65', '25', '43', '91', '52', '97', '51'], 
['70', '11', '33', '28', '77', '73', '17', '78', '39', '68', '17'], 
['91', '71', '52', '38', '17', '14', '91', '43', '58', '50', '27', '29'], 
['63', '66', '04', '68', '89', '53', '67', '30', '73', '16', '69', '87', '40'], 
['04', '62', '98', '27', '09', '70', '98', '73', '93', '38', '53', '60', '04', **'23'**]]

As you can see, python removed the wrong element. I don't understand why?
I tried writing a lot of print statements but I couldn't figure out why the python removes the wrong element.
I have also tried converting all the elements from str to int but the problem is still there.
When I try this:
for i[:] in working_list[:]:
            print(f"removing {i[-1]}")
            i.remove(i[-1])

it removes the whole last row!

remove removes the first element it finds the matches the input. Use del or pop to remove an item at a specific index.

Also, the problem is unclear. It says, "far right column". So, is it the far-right column of the given row (0, 1, 2, 3, etc), or always the last item in the row (-1)?

What if the sum on the left equals the right, would you remove the left of the right side?

Here is my solution for your algorithm, I've left comments in the code, but if you have anymore questions feel free to ask.
data ="""75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33"""
    
data_listed = [i.split(" ") for i in data.split("\n")]

while data_listed:
    left_sum = sum([int(v[0]) for v in data_listed]) # get sum of the most left
    right_sum = sum([int(v[-1]) for v in data_listed]) # get sum of the most right
    # pop either left of right elements based on the sum
    [data_listed[i].pop(-1) if left_sum >= right_sum else data_listed[i].pop(0) for i in range(len(data_listed))] 
    data_listed = [x for x in data_listed if x != []] # remove all empty lists  
    print(f"left_sum = {left_sum},right_sum = {right_sum}")
    [print(d) for d in data_listed]

output:
left_sum = 472,right_sum = 522
['64']
['47', '82']
['35', '87', '10']
['04', '82', '47', '65']
['01', '23', '75', '03', '34']
['02', '77', '73', '07', '63', '67']
['65', '04', '28', '06', '16', '70', '92']
['41', '26', '56', '83', '40', '80', '70', '33']
left_sum = 259,right_sum = 447
['82']
['87', '10']
['82', '47', '65']
['23', '75', '03', '34']
['77', '73', '07', '63', '67']
['04', '28', '06', '16', '70', '92']
['26', '56', '83', '40', '80', '70', '33']
left_sum = 381,right_sum = 383
['10']
['47', '65']
['75', '03', '34']
['73', '07', '63', '67']
['28', '06', '16', '70', '92']
['56', '83', '40', '80', '70', '33']
...
left_sum = 217,right_sum = 192
['70']
['80', '70']
left_sum = 150,right_sum = 140
['80']
left_sum = 80,right_sum = 80

You can use pop() function to remove data from the list.
For example you can remove the last value in second list like that:
data_listed = [['10'],['47', '65']]
data_listed[1].pop(-1)

